# Mandatory Drop-Down List with Alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The code in source file looks like this:

```
<select id="new_user_type_topbar" name="new_user_type_topbar" class="form-control" >
<option value="0">Select fruit</option>
<option value="2">Apple</option>
<option value="3">Orange</option>
<option value="4">Banana</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to do is to make mandatory selection in this drop-down list.

If nothing is selected and the default value is in the drop-down list, then user needs to get a message "Select fruit".

I **need** to do this with JS and here is the (non-functioning) code:

```
if (!jQuery('#new_user_type_topbar').val()=='0') {
jQuery('#register_message_area_topbar').empty().append('<div class="login-alert">Select fruit</div>');
return;
}
```

Please pay attention to the exclamantion point in "!jQuery ...".

I don't see where the issue with the code is.

Can someone please send **code suggestions** regarding how to improve the code?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you trigger your js code, change event or ?

Comment: Also you if statement says  " if value is not equal to 0".

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: Thanks for your reply. Apologies - I am not JS expert. Can you please tell me what in the .js file I need to find to answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the code is:

```
if (jQuery('#new_user_type_topbar').val()=='0') {
jQuery('#register_message_area_topbar').empty().append('<div class="login-alert">Select fruit</div>');
return;
}
```

and it just needs to be placed in the right place in the script.